# How to see latest changes in a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

I have a 112-page Google Doc. It has 10 versions. I selected the latest version in version history, but there 112 pages. How can I see the latest changes?

Answer (score 5):

On the right side of the sub-header, the total edits in each version are shown after you select a specific version. You can cycle through the edits by clicking on the down or up arrows.
[image]